# Is it possible to associate automatd cases in Specflow and Selenium to Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, specflow, microsoft-test-manager

I have some test scenarios and cases written in Specflow/Selenium in Visual Studio, usin MsTest. I just want to associate them to Microsoft Test Manager, so a test case written there is associated to an automated test.

Is that possible? How?

More Data: test were created by using Scenario Outline with some lines of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate testcases to a workitem in TFS/MTM, but we found it to cumbersome to do: It is a manual action in MTM that references the `TestMethod` by name. But because the `TestMethod` is generated by specflow by combining the title of the `Scenario Outline` and the first column of your `Examples` table, it is difficult to maintain:

- Whenever a `Scenario Outline` title is changed, or the term in the first column of the examples table is changed, you have to re-couple the `TestMethods` to the workitems
- When you add new `Examples` or `Scenarios` to your feature, you have to remember to link them to the workitem, one-by-one
- To find the correct `TestMethod` in the dll is nearly undoable when you approach the thousandish scenarios.

What we did was using the `WorkItem` attribute in the `Feature` to connect (parts of) the feature to a workitem like `@Workitem:42` . This is a [little unnoticed feature](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/changelog.txt) in SpecFlow:

> MsTest: Support for MSTest's [Owner] and [WorkItem] attributes with tags like @owner:foo @workitem:123 (Issue 162, Pull 161)

and it creates a [`WorkItemAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.workitemattribute.aspx) attached to the method that is connected to that tagged `Scenario (Outline)` or `Feature`.
Then, we imported all testcases into MTM with the [Test Case Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942471.aspx) tool and ran a custom made tool (making use of the [TeamFoundation namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation(v=vs.120).aspx) and the [TestManagement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.aspx) and [WorkItemTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client(v=vs.120).aspx) Client) that connected each imported `testcase` to the correct `workitem`.
Whenever a test did run we could see the results in MTM, but also from the perspective of the connected workitem.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will do something different then.

Comment: how about automatic import into a test suite using tcm.exe?